# Create dynamic files in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, file-io

I am developing a website using GWT deployed in Google App Engine. With the data introduced by the user I would like to generate a .JS file.

Are we allowed to create and store these files in Google App Engine? I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Which function would you use for the .JS file creation, taking into account that data includes special characters (some non-printable characters in ASCII)?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with this javascript? Store it persistently? Serve it back to the user on the request that created it? Something else?

Comment: Hi Nick. Yes, I want to serve it back to the user, there is no need to store it persistently. Does it change mamoo's answer? THANKS

Comment: Yes - you don't need to write a file at all - just generate the javascript and send it straight back to the user as the body of the response, the same as you would if you were serving up an HTML page.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case I think I will need to write a file, because the javascript contains some "non printable" parameters that sometimes are not displayed properly in the browser (so that user can copy&paste). So it is better to generate a .JS file to avoid this problem. I will try to use BLOBS then.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing special about 'files' - if you're having problems with unicode, writing it to a file will not solve it. All you need to do, in either case, is return it with the correct mimetype and encoding. Likewise, storing blobs won't make any difference. If you need to serve Javascript to a user, just generate it and serve it up. If you're having encoding issues, ask about them here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not allowed...

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem.
> Applications must use the App Engine datastore for storing persistent
> data. Reading from the filesystem is allowed, and all application
> files uploaded with the application are available.
>
> open a socket or
> access another host directly. An application can use the App Engine
> URL fetch service to make HTTP and HTTPS requests to other hosts on
> ports 80 and 443, respectively.
>
> spawn a sub-process or thread. A web
> request to an application must be handled in a single process within a
> few seconds. Processes that take a very long time to respond are
> terminated to avoid overloading the web server. make other kinds of
> system calls.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox

Comment: ...which is completely beside the point, because presumably what the user wants to do is serve the javascript to the user - which is perfectly practical - not store it on the server's local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Exactly, what I want to do is to serve it to the user, not store it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate files *per se* but as of recently, you are allowed to programmatically create **blobs** in the Blobstore using an API named - incidentally - [Files API](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). If you specifiy the blob's MIME type as `text/javascript`, you can then [serve it](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob) via Blobstore download handler in a way that mimics a static JS file.

Comment: It seems to be interesting. I will have a look... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible; but as long as the JS files you need to generate are smaller than 1MB, you can store them into the datastore; I'd be happy to give you an basic application you can host files up to 10MB on GAE with, that only uses the Datastore API. (Python)

Comment: I do not need to store it persistently, just serve this file back to the user. I am using Java, not Python, but I will try to store it somehow in the datastore. Thanks!